# Is there a way to assign the output of a step to another environment variable on Bitrise?

Tags: bitrise

The Xcode archive step creates this variable: `${BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR}` and read that `pilot` uses the `PILOT_IPA` environment variables for the IPA directory.

Is there a way to assign the output (`BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR`) to another environment variable (e.g.: `$PILOT_IPA`)?

Comment: Xcode archive does not create the variable `${BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR}` however.  If you want to deploy your app you can use `${BITRISE_IPA_PATH}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that by using `envman` (https://github.com/bitrise-io/envman) which is part of the `bitrise` CLI tool stack.

To assign the value of an existing Environment Variable (Step outputs are just regular Environment Variables) you can use a Script step, and specify this as the content:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR: $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR"
envman add --key PILOT_IPA --value "$BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR"
```

This'll first print the value of the `BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR` environment variable, and then with `envman add` it'll add a new environment item with the key `PILOT_IPA` and the value of `$BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR`.